# Header followed by a horizontal line

Tags: cv

how can I create a section title followed by a horizontal line which extends to the right margin as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a short but complete code with what you've tried? We don't even know your document class.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

If you don't need the section number, you can either just use `\section*{First Section}` or change the example as follows (this might be troublesome if you need a table of contents):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\sectionrule}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{{\color{cyan}\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}}\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\,\sectionrule[0.5ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

  \section{First Section}
  \blindtext
  
  \section{Second Section}
  \blindtext

\end{document}
```

I've found a five years old [answer of Bernards’](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246511/220875) which I've only slightly adapted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\sectionrule}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{{\color{cyan}\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}}\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1\,\sectionrule[0.5ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}

  \section{First Section}
  \blindtext
  
  \section{Second Section}
  \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal rule]

Comment: could you please give me the link to the original answer? thx

Comment: @billgreg, I've added the link.

Comment: thank you! how do I get rid of the number before the section name?

Comment: @billgreg, see the edit, please.